# SAP Fiori application development in angular?

Tags: angularjs, sapui5, sap-fiori

we are developing an application using HTML/CSS and using the Angular framework. The problem is that we are quite a ways in to development and our client is switching to SAP, I have looked and looked and all I can find is information about SAPUI5 and Fiori. Is there a way we can still use our Angular app as a Fiori application or would we have to switch everything to SAPUI5, it sounds like a lot of work for a custom application that is practically done but I'm not an SAP expert so I was hoping someone could provide some insight around working with Fiori apps.

Thanks -

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in general it is probably a good idea to choose either one of the frameworks. Changing to SAP is a bit general, i assume you do mean here SAP HANA cloud platform? If so there is no reason, why you would not be able to use angularjs to continue your application and just use the backend data services via for instance an odata service (which also should be present for a lot of other SAP applications, there is also SAP Gateway to enable this).
So all in all i think it will be possible to go ahead with angularjs, at the end also SAPUI5 is just a frontend framework.
Quick search on sdn.sap.com brings up some interesting articles that might be of help for you like the following.
http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2013/12/15/openui5-or-angularjs-how-about-both

Comment: Thank you very much, that is very helpful. I was not able to find anything when I was trying google, probably because I know almost nothing about SAP.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what is mentioned in AirBorne04 answer, if you continue to build AngularJS application consuming oData services provided by SAP backend, you will loose all the features provided by Fiori Launchpad (which are many btw). See the link https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/f9/51b50a07ce41deb08ced62711fe8b5/frameset.htm

Technically, this is not an issue but suppose if your customer wants to implement Fiori Launchpad then it will be an issue. So I suggest that you inform the customer about this in advance so that there are no surprises later on.